# What can I do so that no matter how long the text all will have same starting alignment?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I do a stateless widget category_card which is going to use four times.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';

class CategoryCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String svgSrc;
  final String title;
  final VoidCallback press;
  const CategoryCard(
      {Key? key,
      required this.svgSrc,
      required this.title,
      required this.press})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.15),
                spreadRadius: 5,
                blurRadius: 7,
                offset: const Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: press,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const Spacer(),
                    SvgPicture.asset(
                      svgSrc,
                      height: 100,
                      width: 100,
                    ),
                    const Spacer(),
                    Text(
                      title,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1!.copyWith(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Colors.blueGrey[900]),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My output is alright, but the text part for long text such as medical condition the word is not align with the shorter word such as allergy. What can I do so that no matter how long the text all will have same starting alignment?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bt3Fm.png)

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to provide a sample image.

Comment: Alright, done insert photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Column` property for making all it's item at the same point

```
Column(
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, // or you can change it depends your need  
children: [
```